# exception while mast type to GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline

Tags: iphone, uncaught-exception, gkpeerpickercontroller

I am using GKPeerPickerController , i need to send message using wifi , so iam using following code

```
         picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];

         picker.connectionTypesMask= GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline;
         picker.delegate = self;
```

but when i use this following error occurs

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GKInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'A     GKPeerPickerController must support GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby at a minimum.'
```

please help how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is your answer: according to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPeerPickerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKPeerPickerController/setConnectionTypesMask%3a): "GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby is required to be one of the allowed connection types. An exception is thrown if your application does not include it."